# Removing Special Characters from URL - HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So for some reason a site I have been working on a redesign for was built using some blogging software (Serendipity) and for further unknown reasons inbound links to the blogs went like this -

http://site_name.co.uk/blog/index.php?/archives/this-is-a-blog-title.html

Using the following redirects in my HTACCESS I managed to redir the links too the new URL structure

http://site_name.co.uk/blog/this-is-a-blog-title

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/?)$                              /news [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/archives/(.+?)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php$                       /news/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/index.php(.*)$                    /news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However an issue appears. Because the old links had the blog title as part of a query string special characters were allowed in the URL for example

http://site_name.co.uk/blog/index.php?/archives/this-is-a-blog-title-google.co.uk.html

This now redirects to

http://site_name.co.uk/news/this-is-a-blog-title-google.co.uk.html

But I'm getting errors because of the '.' in my URL.

I'm hoping there is a some sort of way to strip these special chars out as well as still redirecting to the new structure.

Comment: What kind of error? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes @MarioA - I get a 404 error when the links contain any periods etc

Comment: I see no problem with periods an an url. The redirect works obviously, but the url isn't served by your application, thus you get a 404

Comment: How do you want the redirected url to look like? dashes instead of periods?

Comment: I believe it is actually the framework that is having issues with the periods in the URL - @MarioA yes dashes would be perfect

Comment: @MarioA figured is within the framework. Thanks for taking the time :) !

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within the framework being used. Issue solved by allowing periods within the framework URL structure.